# 2nd inline element is pushed down a few px?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/HEQbt/1/

I have two inline elements that both have line-height set.  The 2nd element, for some reason, is getting pushed down a few px.  Wondering if anyone knows why?

FF/Chrome tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align: top;` to your anchor.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.  I'd tried adding that to the div previously to no avail.